# count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, null given

Tags: php, laravel-9

I'm a Laravel newbie. Getting this error with count() method. Also tried it with is_countable() but still the same. isset() always returns false. Tried everything I know.

Here is the listing.blade.php

```
<h1>{{ $heading }}</h1>
@unless(count($listings)== 0)
    @foreach ($listings as $listing)
        <h2>
            <a href="/listings/{{ $listing['$id'] }}>{{ $listing['title'] }}"></a>
        </h2>
        <p>
            {{ $listing['description'] }}
        </p>
    @endforeach
@else
    <p>No listings Found</p>
@endunless
```

Controller

```
class listing
{
    public static function all(){
        return [
                [
                    'id' => 1,
                    'title' =>'Listing One',
                    'description' => 'Lorem ipsum'
                ],
                [
                    'id' => 2,
                    'title' =>'Listing Two',
                    'description' => 'Lorem ipsum'
                ]
        ];
    }

    public static function find($id){
        $listings = self::all();
        foreach($listings as $listing){
            if($listing[$id]==$id){
                return $listing;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Web.php

```
Route :: get('/', function(){
    return view('listings', [
        'heading' => 'Latest Listings',
        'Listings' => listing::all()
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Any parameter that you're passing to the view should be exactly the same, as it's case sensitive.
So, in `Web.php`, you're passing `Listings` to the view, but in `listing.blade.php` you're referring to it as `$listings`.

Try changing `Web.php` to:

```php
Route :: get('/', function(){
    return view('listings', [
        'heading' => 'Latest Listings',
        'listings' => listing::all()
    ]);
});
```

Comment: Okay, now I'm getting undefined array key '$id' in listings.blade.php

Comment: Because you wrote `$listing['$id']` instead of `$listing['id']`...